# Alarm clock in Java

Tags: java, timer, clock, alarm

I want to make a program that will make a pop-up appear at a certain time in the future, eg. 5:00 tonight. Basically, the program is a reminder/notification system for appointments, meetings, etc.

My first instinct was to create a sort of "Clock Listener" that would check the computer's time every minute or so and see if currentTime == alarmTime. However, I don't know if this takes up too much resources or if it is just a bad practice to have your program constantly doing things like that. Also, for the alarm to be accurate, I think it would need to check every second, rather than every minute (since if it isn't checking the seconds and will go off at 5:00:xx, it could go off at 5:00:59, which may be too late for some people's liking). Is checking the clock every second too much?

My second thought was when the program starts running, calculate how long it is until the alarm is set to go off (say, in five hours). Then, wait five hours, and then sound the alarm. But then I thought, though unlikely, it would be possible for the user to change the computer's time, and then the alarm would go off at the wrong time. So this doesn't really work.

I've seen some solutions that use threads, but I'm not familiar with those yet, so I'd rather not use them.

I'm leaning towards the first solution, but I want to make sure it's efficient and won't slow down other programs. Perhaps I'm overthinking it and checking the clock is a trivial operation, but I just wanted to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong.

Comment: I understand the idea, is this going to be a Desktop application ? if yes, do you want to develop it only for some particular operating system?

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping for it to be a program for Windows that runs in the background and then only pop-ups when the alarm is set to go off.

Comment: Go with the first one. Checking the time every second is trivial for a computer working in GigaHertz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first solution is OK. Waking up, checking the time, and going back to sleep should not be a problem at all. You can check every second if you want, but if you only need 1-minute resolution perhaps it is enough to check e.g. every 30 seconds.

The second approach has the problem you have outlined already. If you just go to sleep for the time remaining, and the user changes the time (or the time is changed by some other means, e.g. synchronisation with a time server), the alarm would go off at the wrong time. You could avoid this if you could register some sort of hook so that your program is called back when the system time changes, but you cannot easily do this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The sleep solution is very straightforward, but using [`java.util.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) is not much harder, and gives you a clear way to extend your utility for multiple alarms, etc. Assuming you are going to use Swing to display the notification, note that your `TimerTask` will need to perform some of its work on the Swing event thread. [`SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) will help you with that.